# mapping columns using their headers in macro

Tags: macros

I have two worksheets. I have to copy values to first worksheet from second worksheet but on basis of column name. 
For coping data from column G to C I am using-
                  If Wks2.Range("C" & I) <> Wks.Range("G" & J).Value Then
                        Wks2.Range("C" & I).Value = Wks.Range("G" & J)
                  End If

But the problem here is that column sequence keeps on changing in secong one. So mapping cannot be hardcoded on column alphabet.
I not sure how to map them using column headers.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can search ColumnName in Header. After find the matching item ,retrieve its row as reference ,

Dim cellRef as integer 
  Set e = Worksheets(2).Rows(1).find(ColumnName)
  If not e is nothing then
    cellRef = e. column
End if

Comment: I did not get it how it would fit in my script. Could you please relate it with my above example.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

So , assume that your columnnames are in Row#1 of worksheets(2) = wks2
Yoh have to find the letter of columnName ( here is "C" )
SearchColumn : wanted columnname
    Dim e As Object
    Set e = Nothing
    Set e = wks2.Range("1:1").Find(SearchColumn)
    If not e is nothing then
         Dim colAddress As String
        colAddress = e.Address
        Dim colLetter As String
        colLetter = Mid(colAddress, 2, InStr(2, colAddress, "$", vbTextCompare) - 2)
        If Wks2.Range(colLetter & I) <> Wks.Range("G" & J).Value Then
            Wks2.Range(colLetter & I).Value = Wks.Range("G" & J)
        End
    Else
        msgbox("Can not find  " & SearchColumn)
    End if

End If

First of All , we find the column ( e )
e.address returns the found column address
then colLetter store the column letter of it.

Please inform me for any question

C